# How to doubly reference child and parent classes within both classes

Tags: c++, c, oop

How can I properly reference child and parent objects within both objects (doubly-linked child and parent)?  When doing that, I get a compilation error: `**** does not name a type`.  I suspect it has to do with the #include statements being omitted due to the #define tags.  How should these tags be hence included?

The three files (Parent.h, Child.h, main.cpp) written as such:

```
    /* Parent.h */
#pragma once
#ifndef _CHILD_CLS
#define _CHILD_CLS

#include "Child.h"

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {}
    ~Parent() {}
    void do_parent(Child* arg);
};
#endif

/* Child.h */
#pragma once
#ifndef _CHILD_CLS
#define _CHILD_CLS

#include "Parent.h"

class Child {
public:
    Child() {}
    ~Child() {}
    void do_child(Parent* arg);
};
#endif

/* main.cpp */
#include "child.h"
#include "parent.h"

int main()
{
    Child   a();
    Parent  b();
    a.do_parent(Child& arg);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined two functions instead of objects, see [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Update

```
Child   a();              // a is a function returns Child object
Parent  b();              // b is a function returns Parent object
a.do_parent(Child& arg);
```

TO

```
Child   a;           // a is a Child object
Parent  b;           // b is a Parent object
b.do_parent(&a);
```

Also, you have [circular include](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) issue, to break circular include, you need to forward one type :

Child.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _CHILD_CLS
#define _CHILD_CLS

//#include "Parent.h"  Don't include Parent.h
class Parent;           // forward declaration
class Child {
public:
    Child() {}
    ~Child() {}
    void do_child(Parent* arg);
};
#endif
```

Child.cpp

```
#include "Parent.h"
// blah
```

Comment: Gee!  Thanks.  That worked.  However, if an instance of Child was in Parent, is there any way (apart from pointers) that this Child instance can be accessed?

Comment: Child can be a member of Parent but you still need to be careful about circular include issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency of header files. Just forward declare either of the classes in one of the headers. For example:

```
    /* Parent.h */
#pragma once
#ifndef _CHILD_CLS
#define _CHILD_CLS

//#include "Child.h"   ----> Remove it
class Child;           //Forward declare it

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {}
    ~Parent() {}
    void do_parent(Child* arg);
};
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks.  How should that be done, e.g. do I declare #include "Parent.h" in the Child header, and #include "Child.h" in the Parent header?

Comment: @toiletfreak: I already showed the code example of how to do it.

Comment: I have tried to place an #include <Child.h> in Parent.h, but it still gives an error of `does not name a type`.

Comment: If you see the code properly you can see I removed `"Child.h"` from being included in `"Parent.h"` and added a forward declaration `class Child;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use class prototypes / forward declarations:

```
class Child;
```

and

```
class Parent;
```

before each others class declaration and remove the includes.

Answer (score 0):

The error, I **guess** (you should always include the *complete* and *unedited* error message when asking about compilation/linker errors), is this line:

```
a.do_parent(Child& arg);
```

You should pass a pointer to a `Child` object here, not a variable declaration:

```
b.do_parent(&a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a *forward declaration* of `class Parent` or `class Child`. Try modifying one of your files.

In you Parent.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _CHILD_CLS
#define _CHILD_CLS

class Child;     // Forward declaration of class Child

class Parent {
public:
    Parent() {}
    ~Parent() {}
    void do_parent(Child* arg);
};
#endif
```

Or in your Child.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _CHILD_CLS
#define _CHILD_CLS

class Parent;    // Forward declaration of class Parent

class Child {
public:
    Child() {}
    ~Child() {}
    void do_child(Parent* arg);
};
#endif
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration) should help you a lot.